# Apache Spark: Unable to build: [error] Server access Error..jetty

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, sbt

I have downloaded spark-1.4.1.tgz, unzipped it.
Now, when i try to build as follows, it gets stuck:

```
           $ ./sbt/sbt assembly
            Invoking 'build/sbt assembly' now
            [info] Loading project definition...
            [warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'.
            ...
            [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-parent;18
    [error] Server access Error: Connection reset url=http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/18/jetty-parent-18.jar
    [error] Server access Error: Server redirected too many  times (20) url=http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/jetty-orbit/1/jars/jetty-orbit.jar
```

The build gets stuck at this point. Am i missing any configuration/libraries?

Comment: download http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/18/jetty-parent-18.jar manually and add it to your local repository, and try again. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I finally ended up downloading the package 'Pre-Built for Hadoop version', instead of 'Source Code' package. No need to compile anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have a network connectivity issue and probably need to retry.